# Algebraic numbers and geometric series - from finite to infinite, similarity with transcendental numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-number-theory

It started with a game I played with the inverse of golden ratio, but now I have some questions about the connection of infinite geometric series and algebraic numbers.

The example first. Since we know that:

$$1=\phi^{-1}+\phi^{-2}$$

We can obtain all the successive powers of $\phi^{-1}$ in terms of higher powers and substitute them in the above equation:

$$\phi^{-2}=\phi^{-3}+\phi^{-4}$$

$$\phi^{-4}=\phi^{-5}+\phi^{-6}$$

We can continue *ad infinitum*. Now we can express $1$ as an infinite sum:

$$1=\phi^{-1}+\phi^{-3}+\phi^{-5}+\phi^{-7}+...=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\phi^{2k-1}}$$

On the one hand, this result is trivial if we know the closed form of geometric sum and notice that $|\phi^{-1}|<1$. The series converge in the limit:

[image: Phi infinite sum convergence]

On the other hand, we can apply this process to any algebraic equation of the general form, for example:

$$1=a_1 x+a_2 x^2+a_3 x^3$$

It would be convenient if we only replaced the highest power, so let's do that:

$$a_3 x^3=a_3(a_1 x^4+a_2 x^5+a_3 x^6)$$

$$a_3 x^{6}=a_3 (a_1 x^{7}+a_2 x^{8}+a_3 x^{9})$$

We get an infinite series:

$$1=a_1 x+a_2 x^2+a_3(a_1 x^4+a_2 x^5+a_3 (a_1 x^{7}+a_2 x^{8}+a_3 (a_1 x^{10}+...)))$$

It is not a pure geometric series, but close enough. For example, if $a_1=a_2=a_3=1$, we can express it as:

$$1=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}x^k-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}x^{3k}$$

This series only converges if $|x|<1$. For example in the cubic equation above for the real root the series converges, but for the complex roots it does not.

Notice, that in general $a_n$ could be negative, also there is no restrictions on $x$, it could be a general complex algebraic number.

**Edit**

I reformulate my question:

> Can we say that all algebraic numbers $|x|<1$ can be viewed as solutions to a certain kind of infinite powers series equations with rational coefficients? Just as transcendental numbers, but with condition that this equation also has a closed finite form? Would this series always be a linear combination of geometric series, or can they have a more general form?

Comment: Well, if $a_n x^n + \dots + a_1x = 1$, then $a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\dots + a_1x = 1 - a_n x^n$, so $1 = \frac{a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\dots + a_1x}{1 - a_nx^n}$, which is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\dots + a_1x)\cdot (a_nx^n)^k$.

Comment: @MarcPaul, thank you, so basically, this is a linear combination of geometric series, correct?